# How to check if a key is empty or not in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am doing react native application. And I am getting json response like below.

```
[
  {
    id: '508',
    class: 'class1',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '8.90',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '509',
    class: 'class2',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '2.40',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '510',
    class: 'class3',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '56.40',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '511',
    class: 'class',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '2.40',
    color: 'black'
  }
]
```

I have to check all the `value` properties are empty or not. If all are empty, I have to do some action else condition other action.

```
  const emptyValues = sortedData.map(value => value.key);
  console.log('emptyValues data', emptyValues);
```

Comment: Note: I'm aware linked question checks for `null` and this post asks for empty values. However, the logic is same and approaches defined addresses solution for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all `value` keys are `'0'` (or whatever your definition of empty is):

```js
const data = [{"id":"508","class":"class1","value":"0","percentage":"8.90","color":"black"},{"id":"509","class":"class2","value":"0","percentage":"2.40","color":"black"},{"id":"510","class":"class3","value":"0","percentage":"56.40","color":"black"},{"id":"511","class":"class","value":"0","percentage":"2.40","color":"black"}]

const doEmptyAction = data.every(o => o.value === '0')

console.log(doEmptyAction)
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to have callback as `o => isEmpty(o.value)` and have a custom `isEmpty` function which would look like `isEmpty = (value) => value === undefined || value === null || value === ''`. We can also check for empty objects/arrays in it. So OP has do define their empty criteria

Comment: Will this returns true or false? And this will check all the indexes, right?

Comment: But, Its always returning false? even the values are 0

Comment: What is your definition of empty?

Comment: I got it, Thank you.

Comment: It will check entire loop of data, right?

Comment: Yes it will, but if it finds a non empty value, and will stop and return `false`. Ready the documentation of every in the link.

Comment: if i want to check if any property is empty or now but I got false! although it's not empty

Comment: @OliverD - create a new question with the data, what you tried, and the expected result.

Comment: @OriDrori [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093759/how-to-check-items-in-an-array-of-objects-is-empty-or-not-using-every)

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr = [
  {
    id: '508',
    class: 'class1',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '8.90',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '509',
    class: 'class2',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '2.40',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '510',
    class: 'class3',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '56.40',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    id: '511',
    class: 'class',
    value: '0',
    percentage: '2.40',
    color: 'black'
  }
];

let desiredVal = arr.map((obj) => {
   if(obj.value){
      //do something
   }
});
```

Comment: Just a general suggestion, an answer is incomplete without explanation.