# How to check items in an array of objects is empty or not using every?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and before I want to send a request I want to appear a message if the price is empty.

So I used `.every` but it's return false always "empty or not"

sample data

```js
const services = [{
    "id": 12,
    "price": "10"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "price": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "price": "99"
  },
]

const isEmpty = (value) => value === undefined || value === null || value === '';

const doEmptyAction = services.every((item) => isEmpty(item.price));

console.log(doEmptyAction); // always false
```

Comment: That is because not every price in your array of object is empty? `Array.prototype.every` requires all prices to be empty, based on your logic. Since some of your prices are "not empty" then it will always return false. Perhaps you are looking for `Array.prototype.some`, if you're trying to find out if **one or more** prices are empty?

Comment: Do you want just to find out is there any non-valid item in your 'services' array - or actually collect all of those? If former, use `Array#some`; if latter, `Array#filter`. `Array#every` will stop iterating after finding the first item that doesn't answer the predicate (and that's the first item of your array actually).

Comment: @Terry hmm yes you're right, I think `.every` if all prices are not empty return false! 
so after using `some` it solves the issue if any price is empty return `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every() does not execute the function for array elements without values. Use some():

```
const services = [{
    "id": 12,
    "price": "10"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "price": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "price": "99"
  },
]

const isEmpty = (value) => value === undefined || value === null || value === '';

const doEmptyAction = services.some((item) => isEmpty(item.price));

console.log(doEmptyAction);
```